# Using cURL and pThread for PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Is it possible to run a cURL request inside a Thread?

I'm always getting Segmentation Fault, if you have any code snippet please post it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

This module provides an easy-to-use interface to allow you to run multiple CURL url fetches in parallel in PHP.